# cudaMemcpy error from Device to Host

Tags: cuda

I am returning a two-dimensional structure after computation on a kernel, from device to host.

```
HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(Pixel,Pixel_gpu,img_wd*img_ht*sizeof(pixel),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
```

Pixel is declared on host, Pixel_gpu is allocated on device, as below:

```
**Pixel_gpu;
HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMalloc(&Pixel_gpu,img_wd*img_ht*sizeof(pixel)));

pixel **Pixel = (pixel**)malloc((img_ht)*sizeof(pixel*));
for(int i=0;i<(img_ht);i++)
    Pixel[i]=(pixel*)malloc((img_wd)*sizeof(pixel));
```

Using this I end up getting illegal memory access error.

Trying a similar memory alignment for result, doesn't help either.

```
 pixel *Pixel_res = (pixel*)malloc(img_wd*img_ht*sizeof(pixel));



HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(Pixel_res,Pixel_gpu,img_wd*img_ht*sizeof(pixel),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
```

Kernel launching:

```
cudaDeviceProp prop;
HANDLE_ERROR(cudaGetDeviceProperties(&prop, 0));


int thread_block=sqrt(prop.maxThreadsPerBlock);
dim3 DimGrid(ceil(img_wd/thread_block),ceil(img_ht/thread_block),1);
dim3 DimBlock(sqrt(prop.maxThreadsPerBlock),sqrt(prop.maxThreadsPerBlock),1);

//allocating gpu memory


pixel **Pixel_tmp_gpu, **Pixel_gpu;


HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMalloc(&Pixel_tmp_gpu,img_wd*img_ht*sizeof(pixel)));
HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMalloc(&Pixel_gpu,img_wd*img_ht*sizeof(pixel)));


float **kernel0_gpu, **kernel1_gpu;

HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMalloc(&kernel0_gpu,k*1*sizeof(float)));
HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMalloc(&kernel1_gpu,1*k*sizeof(float)));

cout<<"memory allocated"<<endl;

//copying needed data

HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(Pixel_tmp_gpu,Pixel_tmp,img_wd*img_ht*sizeof(pixel),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(Pixel_gpu,Pixel,img_wd*img_ht*sizeof(pixel),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(kernel0_gpu,kernel0,k*1*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(kernel1_gpu,kernel1,1*k*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

cout<<"memory transfers done"<<endl;

vertical_conv<<<DimGrid,DimBlock>>>(Pixel_gpu, Pixel_tmp_gpu,img_wd, img_ht,kernel0_gpu,k);
time_t vertical_convolution=time(NULL);

cout<<" vertical_convolution time: "<<double(vertical_convolution - reading_file)<<"sec"<<endl;


horizontal_conv<<<DimGrid,DimBlock>>>(Pixel_tmp_gpu, Pixel_gpu, img_wd, img_ht, kernel1_gpu, k);
time_t horizontal_convolution=time(NULL);

cout<<" horizontal convolution time:" <<double(horizontal_convolution-vertical_convolution)<<" sec"<<endl;

pixel *Pixel_res = (pixel*)malloc(img_wd*img_ht*sizeof(pixel));

HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(Pixel_res,Pixel_gpu,img_wd*img_ht*sizeof(pixel),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
```

The functions used:

```
struct  pixel //to store RGB values
{
    unsigned char r;
    unsigned char g;
    unsigned char b;
};

static void HandleError( cudaError_t err, const char *file, int line ) {
    if (err != cudaSuccess) {
        cout<<cudaGetErrorString(err)<<" in "<< file <<" at line "<< line<<endl;
    }
}

#define HANDLE_ERROR( err ) (HandleError( err, __FILE__, __LINE__ ))

__device__ void padding(pixel** Pixel_val, int x_coord, int y_coord, int img_width, int img_height, pixel Px) //padding the image,depending on pixel coordinates, can be replaced by reflect for better result //currently zero padding
{
    if(x_coord<img_width && y_coord<img_height && x_coord>=0 && y_coord>=0) 
        Px=Pixel_val[y_coord][x_coord];
}
```

The vertical convolution:

```
__global__ void vertical_conv(pixel** Pixel_in, pixel** Pixel_out,int img_wd, int img_ht, float** kernel, int k)
{
    float tmp_r, tmp_g, tmp_b;
    pixel pix_val;
    pix_val.r=0;pix_val.g=0;pix_val.b=0;
    int row=blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    int col = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if(row<img_ht && col<img_wd){
        tmp_r=0, tmp_g=0, tmp_b=0;
        for(int l=0;l<k;l++)
        {   

            padding(Pixel_in, col, row+l-(k-1)/2, img_wd, img_ht, pix_val);
            tmp_r+=pix_val.r * kernel[l][0];
            tmp_b+=pix_val.b * kernel[l][0];
            tmp_g+=pix_val.g * kernel[l][0];
        }

        Pixel_out[row][col].r=tmp_r;
        Pixel_out[row][col].g=tmp_g;
        Pixel_out[row][col].b=tmp_b;
    }
}
```

The horizontal convolution:

```
   __global__ void horizontal_conv(pixel** Pixel_in, pixel** Pixel_out, int img_wd, int img_ht, float** kernel, int k)
{
    float tmp_r, tmp_b, tmp_g;
    pixel pix_val;
    pix_val.r=0;pix_val.g=0;pix_val.b=0;

    //horizontal convolution
    int row=blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    int col = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    tmp_r=0, tmp_g=0, tmp_b=0;
    if(row<img_ht && col<img_wd)
    {
        for(int l=0; l<k;l++)
        {
            padding(Pixel_in, col+l-(k-1)/2, row, img_wd, img_ht, pix_val);
            tmp_r+=pix_val.r * kernel[0][l];
            tmp_g+=pix_val.g * kernel[0][l];
            tmp_b+=pix_val.b * kernel[0][l];
        }
        Pixel_out[row][col].r=tmp_r;
        Pixel_out[row][col].g=tmp_g;
        Pixel_out[row][col].b=tmp_b;
    }
}
```

Can someone help me know what could be wrong here?

Comment: You can't pass a flat, single-pointer (`*`) allocation to the kernel and expect to use it as a double-pointer (`**`) array.  Passing double-pointer arrays between host and device requires special coding, which you are missing.  This is a frequently misunderstood topic, so there are plenty of questions discussing it.  You can just search on `cuda 2D array` or   the `cuda` tag info page links to a canonical question discussing how to handle 2D arrays.  And I believe this is still not an [mcve].  It should be something that someone else can compile and run, without a lot of assembly work.

Comment: You will simplify your job considerably if you just convert everything to single-pointer arrays with simulated 2D access (i.e. `[row*width+col]`).

Comment: I will look into 2D array handling on cuda, thanks for suggesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Pixel_gpu` is be **one** contiguous memory block, consisting of `w*h` elements of type `pixel`. Its size is

```
sizeOfDeviceMemory = img_wd * img_ht * sizeof(pixel)
```

On contrast to that, `Pixel` on the CPU side is an "array of pointers": The `Pixel` pointer points to `h` elements of type `pixel*`. Its size is

```
sizeOfHostMemory = img_ht * sizeof(pixel*)
```

Clearly, these sizes are different, and trying to write `sizeOfDeviceMemory` bytes to this pointer causes an illegal access.

---

Usually, you should allocate your memory on the host as one contiguous block as well:

```
pixel* Pixel = (pixel*)malloc(img_wd * img_ht * sizeof(pixel));
```

Then you can copy the memory to this pointer using the `cudaMemcpy` call that you already have.

---

If having a `pixel*` on the host is not OK for you, and you urgently need a `pixel**` (for example, to pass it to some other function), then you can create an "array of pointers" like you had before, but *not* allocate new memory for each row, but instead, let each pointer point to one "row" of the single, contiguous pixel block.

Comment: I tried allocating host memory as one block, but still got same error.

Comment: The illegal memory access error may be happening in the kernel.  You haven't shown a [mcve] so people are just guessing here.  What Marco13 has pointed out is certainly a defect in your code, but since you haven't shown a complete code, nobody can tell you what all the problems may be.  If you are passing `Pixel_gpu` as a double pointer (`**`) you are almost certainly going to have trouble in your kernel.

Comment: Indeed, the `**Pixel_gpu;` also looks a bit odd. It should be declared as `pixel *Pixel_gpu`. You can then allocate it with `cudaMalloc(&Pixel_gpu,...)` and use it with `cudaMemcpy(..., Pixel_gpu, ...)`. How is `Pixel_gpu` declared? As Robert pointed out, due to the asynchronous nature, it's hard to guess what might now be wrong. For debugging, you could add a `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` **before** and **after** your `cudaMemcpy` call, to make sure that this call is where the problem comes from.